# R programming: data match then select then stop and cont from next position

Tags: r, loops

Request for your help on below problem. I have two datasets.

first table demoa (two columns X and Z)

```
X   Z
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   5
6   6
7   7
8   8
9   9
10  10
```

second dataset demob (two columns Y and W)

```
Y   W
1   2
4   3
7   6
10  9
8   7
2   1
2   1
1   4
```

Now I want to apply this rule: (x[i] <= y[j]) && (z[i] == w[j]). But my conditions are: after the first (i=1) successful match, the loop should stop and print the value to files (y,w) and then it should start from x[i=2] and z[i=2]. If no match found the loop will automatically go to next iteration. So, desired result should look like below -

```
Result
Y   W
2   1
4   3
7   6
8   7
10  9
```

So I have written the below code in R, but facing some issue with position of flag:

```
## output tables
demo_a <- data.frame(x = numeric(1000), y = character(1000), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
demo_b <- data.frame(x = numeric(1000), y = character(1000), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## code starts
for(i in seq(from=1, to=nrow(demoa), by=1))
{
    print(i)
    datamatch = 1
    for(j in seq(from=1, to=nrow(demob), by=1))
    {
        print(i)
        while(datamatch == 1)
        {
            if((demoa$x[i] <= demob$y[j]) && (demoa$z[i] == demob$w[j]))
            {
                print(demoa$x[i])
                print(demob$y[j])
                print(demoa$z[i])
                print(demob$w[j])
                demo_a$x[i] <- demoa[i,1]
                demo_a$y[i] <- demoa[i,2]
                demo_b$x[j] <- demob[j,1]
                demo_b$y[j] <- demob[j,2]
                datamatch = 0
            }
            else
            {
                datamatch = 1
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Can anyone please suggest.

Comment: use lappy https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd try:

```
res<-outer(x,y,`<=`) & outer(z,w,`==`)
cbind(y,w)[setdiff(max.col(res,"first")*NA^!rowSums(res),NA),]
#      y w
#[1,]  2 1
#[2,]  4 3
#[3,]  7 6
#[4,]  8 7
#[5,] 10 9
```

If you want to see all the values, you can try:

```
cbind(cbind(x,z)[which(rowSums(res)!=0),],
      cbind(y,w)[setdiff(max.col(res,"first")*NA^!rowSums(res),NA),])
#     x z  y w
#[1,] 1 1  2 1
#[2,] 3 3  4 3
#[3,] 6 6  7 6
#[4,] 7 7  8 7
#[5,] 9 9 10 9
```

**DATA**

```
x<-1:10
y<-c(1, 4, 7, 10, 8, 2, 2, 1)
w<-c(2, 3, 6, 9, 7, 1, 1, 4)
z<-1:10
```

Comment: it works fine; just an additional query if you don't mind. How to print X and Z values also besides Y and W from same query. I mean X and Z values which are satisfying the conditions and causing match with Y and W value printed in outputs.

Comment: @Zico Made an edit. See it it responds to your query.